# Questions and Verifications on immutable [string] objects c++

Tags: c++, string, object, immutability

I've been doing some reading on immutable strings in general and in c++, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916358/immutable-strings-vs-stdstring), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132502/how-are-c-strings-stored), and I think I have a decent understanding of how things work. However I have built a few assumptions that I would just like to run by some people for verification. Some of the assumptions are more general than the title would suggest:

- While a const string in c++ is the closest thing to an immutable string in STL, it is only locally immutable and therefore doesn't experience the benefit of being a smaller object. So it has all the trimmings of a standard string object but it can't access all of the member functions. This means that it doesn't create any optimization in the program over non-const? But rather just protects the object from modification? I understand that this is an important attribute but I'm simply looking to know what it means to use this
- I'm assuming that an object's member functions exist only once in read-only memory, and how is probably implementation specific, so does a const object have a separate location in memory? Or are the member functions limited in another way? If there are only 'const string' objects and no non-const strings in a code base, does the compiler leave out the inaccessible functions?
- I recall hearing that each string literal is stored only once in read-only memory in c++, however I don't find anything on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327841/c-string-literal-data-type-storage). In other words, if I use some string literal multiple times in the same program, each instance references the same location in memory. I'm going to assume no, but would two string objects initialized by the same string literal point to the same string until one is modified?

I apologize if I have included too many disjunct thoughts in the same post, they are all related to me as string representation and just learning how to code better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, std::string cannot assume that the input string is a read-only constant string from your data segment. Therefore, point (3) does not apply. It will most likely allocate a buffer and copy the string in the buffer.

Note that C++ (like C) has a const qualifier for compilation time, it is a good idea to use it for two reasons: (a) it will help you find bugs, a statement such as `a = 5;` if `a` is declared `const` fails to compile; (b) the compile may be able to optimize the code more easily (it may otherwise not be able to figure out that the object is constant.)

However, C++ has a special cast to remove the `const`-ness of a variable. So our `a` variable can be cast and assigned a value as in `const_cast<int&>(a) = 5;`. An `std::string` can also get its `const`-ness removed. (Note that C does not have a special cast, but it offers the exact same behavior: `* (int *) &a = 5`)

Are all class members defined in the final binary?

No. `std::string` as most of the STL uses templates. Templates are compiled once per unit (your .o object files) and the link will reduce duplicates automatically. So if you look at the size of all the .o files and add them up, the final output will be a lot small.

That also means only the functions that are used in a unit are compiled and saved in the object file. Any other function "disappear". That being said, often function A calls function B, so B will be defined, even if you did not explicitly call it.

On the other hand, because these are templates, very often the functions get inlined. But that is a choice by the compiler, not the language or the STL (although you can use the `inline` keyword for fun; the compiler has the right to ignore it anyway).

Smaller objects... No, in C++ an object has a very specific size that cannot change. Otherwise the sizeof(something) would vary from place to place and C/C++ would go berserk!

Static strings that are saved in read-only data sections, however, can be optimized. If the linker/compiler are good enough, they will be able to merge the same string in a single location. These are just plan `char *` or `wchar_t *`, of course. The Microsoft compiler has been able to do that one for a while now.

Yet, the const on a string does not always force your string to be put in a read-only data section. That will generally depend on your command line option. C++ may have corrected that, but I think C still put everything in a read/write section unless you use the correct command line option. That's something you need to test to make sure (your compiler is likely to do it, but without testing you won't know.)

Finally, although std::string may not use it, C++ offers a quite interesting keyword called mutable. If you heard about it, you would know that a variable member can be marked as mutable and that means even const functions can modify that variable member. There are two main reason for using that keyword: (1) you are writing a multi-thread program and that class has to be multi-thread safe, in that case you mark the mutex as mutable, very practical; (2) you want to have a buffer used to cache a computed value which is costly, that buffer is only initialized when that value is requested to not waste time otherwise, that buffer is made mutable too.

Therefore the "immutable" concept is only really something that you can count on at a higher level. In practice, reality is often quite different. For example, an std::string `c_str()` function may reallocate the buffer to add the necessary '\0' terminator, yet that function is marked as being a `const`:

```
const CharT* c_str() const;
```

Actually, an implementation is free to allocate a completely different buffer, copy its existing data to that buffer and return that bare pointer. That means internally the `std::string` could be allocate many buffers to store large strings (instead of using `realloc()` which can be costly.)

Once thing, though... when you *copy* string A into string B (`B = A;`) the string data does not get copied. Instead A and B will share the same data buffer. Once you modify A or B, and only then, the data gets copied. This means calling a function which accepts a string by copy does not waste that much time:

```
int func(std::string a)
{
    ...
    if(some_test)
    {
        // deep copy only happens here
        a += "?";
    }
}

std::string b;
func(b);
```

The characters of string b do not get copied at the time func() gets called. And if func() never modifies 'a', the string data remains the same all along. This is often referenced as a *shallow copy* or *copy on write*.